# Django CreateView not redirecting to success url

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'm implementing the following CreateView, which is supposed to redirect to a product list after a product has been added to my application. When the form is submitted, the product is successfully added, but the user is not redirected. Instead, the same product form is loaded.

```py
class ProductCreate(CreateView):
    model = Product
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'catalog/product/add_product.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.category = get_object_or_404(Category, form.instance.category)
        return super(ProductCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('product_detail', kwargs={'id': self.object.pk, 'slug': self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['customers'] = Customer.objects.filter(company=self.request.user.profile.company)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.filter(company=self.request.user.profile.company)
        return context
```

Again, the data is successfully stored into the database, but the redirection is not working at all after the form is saved. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Change your `get_success_url()` method so that it should return the URL of the page you want redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your `get_success_url`

```py
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('product_detail', kwargs={'id': self.object.pk, 'slug': self.object.slug})
```

you are redirecting back to product detail page, you should redirect to product list page, assuming your url is named as `product_list`, go check your urls.py and use the correct one if my assumption is wrong.

```py
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('product_list')
```

Comment: I changed it to the correct url name in the reverse_lazy function, but it still does not redirect correctly, and just reloads the page with a blank form.

Comment: The new get_success_url goes as follows: `def get_success_url(self):
  return reverse_lazy('catalog:product_list')` and in the urls.py, there's this path: `path('catalog/', views.product_list, name='product_list'),`

Comment: You will need to do some debugging, try adding print statements in `get_success_url` and the `product_list` view, see if you are seeing the print statements, also what's the url look like when you submitted?

Comment: I added a print statement to get_success_url, but it doesn't show in the dev server. The url that displays after submitting is the same as before submitting. But the object is successfully created in the database. It for some reason is not accessing get_success_url method

Comment: Also add the print statements the `form_valid` method, I suspect your form submit is invalid.